# how to partition steps in spring-batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am learning spring batch and wrote simple application to play with it.
Acccording my requirements I read from single csv file, do some transformation and insert into database.

I have followng configuration:

```
    @Bean
    public Step step1(JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<Person, Person>chunk(10)
                .reader(reader())
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }

   @Bean
    public Job importUserJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener, Step step1, Step step2) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener)
                .listener(new JobExecutionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
                        System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!SECOND_LISTENER_BEFORE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
                        System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!SECOND_LISTENER_AFTER!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

                    }
                })
                .flow(step1)
                .next(step2)
                .end()
                .build();
    }

public FlatFileItemReader reader() {
    return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder()
        .name("csvPersonReader")
        .resource(csvResource)
        .delimited()
        .names(new String[]{"firstName", "lastName"})
        .fieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Person>() {{
            setTargetType(Person.class);
        }})
        .build();

}
```

Now I want to make that step executing using 10 threads. As far I understood I need to use partitioning feaure for that. I've found several examples about it but it contains XML configuration. I prefer to use java configuration.

How can I achieve it ?

### P.S.

I tried the following approach:

```
@Bean
public Step step1(JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer) {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(1);
    TaskletStep step1 = stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<Person, Person>chunk(10)
            .reader(reader())
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writer)
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
            .build();

    return step1;
}
```

But my application hangs. Moreover it doesn't a partition and will work only on a single PC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below code to implement batch Partition.

```
@Configuration
public class DemoJobBatchConfiguration {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoJobBatchConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("applicaionDS")
    public DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    UserWritter userWriter;

    @Bean("demoJob")
    public Job partitionJob(JobNotificationListener listener, JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,
            @Qualifier("demoPartitionStep") Step demoPartitionStep) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("demoJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).listener(listener)
                .start(demoPartitionStep).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "demoPartitionStep")
    public Step demoPartitionStep(Step demoSlaveStep, StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("demoPartitionStep").partitioner("demoPartitionStep", demoPartitioner())
                .gridSize(21).step(demoSlaveStep).taskExecutor(jobTaskExecutor()).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "demoPartitioner", destroyMethod = "")
    public Partitioner demoPartitioner() {
        DemoPartitioner partitioner = new DemoPartitioner();
        // partitioner.partition(20);
        return partitioner;
    }

    @Bean
    public Step demoSlaveStep(ItemReader<User> demoReader, ItemProcessor<User, User> demoJobProcessor) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("demoSlaveStep").<User, User>chunk(3).reader(demoReader)
                .processor(demoJobProcessor).writer(userWriter).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "demoReader")
    @StepScope
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<User> demoReader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext[SQL]}") String SQL,
            @Value("#{jobParameters[JOB_PARM]}") String jobParm,
            @Value("#{jobExecutionContext[jobExecutionParameter]}") String jobExecutionParameter) {
        LOGGER.info("---------------------- demoReader ------------------------------- " + SQL);
        LOGGER.info(" jobParm : " + jobParm);
        LOGGER.info(" jobExecutionParameter : " + jobExecutionParameter);

        JdbcCursorItemReader<User> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
        reader.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
        reader.setFetchSize(200);
        reader.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(User.class));
        reader.setSql(SQL);
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean(name = "demoJobProcessor")
    @StepScope
    public ItemProcessor<User, User> demoJobProcessor() throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info(" DemoJobBatchConfiguration: demoJobProcessor  ");
        return new UserProcessor();
    }

    /*
     * @Bean public ItemWriter<User> demoWriter() { return users -> { for (User user
     * : users) { if (LOGGER.isInfoEnabled()) { LOGGER.info("user read is :: " +
     * user.toString()); } } if (LOGGER.isInfoEnabled()) {
     * LOGGER.info("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% demoWriter %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% "); } };
     * }
     */

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor jobTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        // there are 21 sites currently hence we have 21 threads
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(30);
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(25);
        taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
        return taskExecutor;
    }

}
```

---

```
public class DemoPartitioner implements Partitioner {

    @Override
    public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {

        Map<String, ExecutionContext> result = new HashMap<String, ExecutionContext>();

        int range = 3;
        int fromId = 1;
        int toId = range;

        for (int i = fromId; i <= gridSize;) {
            ExecutionContext executionContext = new ExecutionContext();
            String SQL = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE ID BETWEEN " + fromId + " AND " + toId;
            System.out.println("SQL : " + SQL);
            executionContext.putInt("fromId", fromId);
            executionContext.putInt("toId", toId);
            executionContext.putString("SQL", SQL);
            executionContext.putString("name", "Thread" + i);
            result.put("partition" + i, executionContext);
            fromId = toId + 1;
            i = fromId;
            toId += range;
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61827296/spring-batch-how-to-reads-5-million-records-in-faster-ways?

Answer (score 2):

Your configuration is wrong. Follow below configuration. You need to decide the logic on which you want to partition. Look at the partition method of partitioner how it is creating a map and adding to Execution Context.

Follow below code

```
@Bean
public Step step1(JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer) {
    TaskletStep step1 = stepBuilderFactory.get("partionerStep")
            .partitioner("slaveStep", partitioner())
            .step(slaveStep())
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public CustomPartitioner partitioner() {
    CustomPartitioner partitioner = new CustomPartitioner();
    return partitioner;
}
```

---

```
public class CustomPartitioner implements Partitioner {

    @Override
    public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {
        Map<String, ExecutionContext> map = new HashMap<>(gridSize);
        int i = 0, k = 1;
        for (Resource resource : resources) {
            ExecutionContext context = new ExecutionContext();
            context.putString("keyName", ""); //Depends on what logic you want to use to split 
            map.put("PARTITION_KEY" + i, context);
            i++;
        }
        return map;
    }
}

@Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(10);
        taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
        return taskExecutor;
    }

@Bean
public Step slaveStep() 
  throws UnexpectedInputException, MalformedURLException, ParseException {
    return steps.get("slaveStep")
                .<Person, Person>chunk(10)
                .reader(reader())
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
}

@Bean
    public Job importUserJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener, Step step1, Step step2) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener)
                .listener(new JobExecutionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
                        System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!SECOND_LISTENER_BEFORE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
                        System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!SECOND_LISTENER_AFTER!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

                    }
                })
                .flow(step1)
                .next(step2)
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    return step1;
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate partitioner implementation. It is not clear for what does it mean: **context.putString("keyName", ""); //Depends on what logic you want to use to split**